# Spark Scala - concatenate column in rows in a certain order

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Okay, I have a table with column definitions and corresponding ordinal positions.  I'm building a metadata-driven ETL framework using Spark (scala).  I have a table that contains the following info:

- tablename
- columnname
- datatype
- ordinalposition

I have to build a CREATE TABLE statement from that data.  Not a big deal, right?  I tried what appears to be the standard answer:

```
var metadatadef = spark.sql("SELECT tablename, columnname, datatype, ordinalposition FROM metadata")
    .withColumn("columndef", concat($"columnname", lit(" "), $"datatype"))
    .sort($"tablename", $"ordinalposition")
    .groupBy("tablename")
    .agg(concat_ws(", ", collect_list($"columndef")).as("columndefs"))
```

But the sort() call seems to be ignored here.  Or between collect_list() and concat_ws() it gets reshuffled.  Given source data like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
| tablename | columnname   | datatype      | ordinalposition |
+ ----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
| table1    | IntColumn    | int           | 0               |
| table2    | StringColumn | string        | 2               |
| table1    | StringColumn | string        | 2               |
| table2    | IntColumn    | int           | 0               |
| table1    | DecColumn    | decimal(15,2) | 1               |
| table2    | DecColumn    | decimal(15,2) | 1               |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

I am trying to get output like this:

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| tablename | columndefs                                                     |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| table1    | IntColumn int, DecColumn decimal(15,2), StringColumn string    |
| table2    | IntColumn int, DecColumn decimal(15,2), StringColumn string    |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Instead, I wind up with something like this:

```
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| tablename | columndefs                                                     |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| table1    | IntColumn int, StringColumn string, DecColumn decimal(15,2)    |
| table2    | StringColumn string, IntColumn int, DecColumn decimal(15,2)    |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Do I need to build a UDF to ensure I get proper order?  I need the output to end up in a dataframe for comparison purposes, not just building the CREATE TABLE statement.

Comment: If you want in a custom order yes udf is the way but if same order is only required you can try `.agg(concat_ws(", ", sort_array(collect_list($"columndef"))).as("columndefs"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `struct` column of (`ordinalposition`, `columndef`) and apply `sort_array` to sort the aggregated `columndef` in the wanted order during the `groupBy` transformation as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = Seq(
  ("table1", "IntColumn", "int", "0"),
  ("table2", "StringColumn", "string", "2"),
  ("table1", "StringColumn", "string", "2"),
  ("table2", "IntColumn", "int", "0"),
  ("table1", "DecColumn", "decimal(15,2)", "1"),
  ("table2", "DecColumn", "decimal(15,2)", "1")
).toDF("tablename", "columnname", "datatype", "ordinalposition")

df.
  withColumn("columndef",
    struct($"ordinalposition", concat($"columnname", lit(" "), $"datatype").as("cdef"))
  ).
  groupBy("tablename").agg(sort_array(collect_list($"columndef")).as("sortedlist")).
  withColumn("columndefs", concat_ws(", ", $"sortedlist.cdef")).
  drop("sortedlist").
  show(false)
// +---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
// |tablename|columndefs                                                 |
// +---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
// |table2   |IntColumn int, DecColumn decimal(15,2), StringColumn string|
// |table1   |IntColumn int, DecColumn decimal(15,2), StringColumn string|
// +---------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Yay! it worked!  Thanks for the advice about sort_array and the struct together.